# VS2022 with LLVM Clang failing to compile static Cpp lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, clang, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to upgrade my static lib project from VS 2017 to VS 2022 also wanted to use LLVM clang support. In my project I have only one class.

```
class MyClass
{
private: 
    int count;
    static int data;
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
};
```

Project builds successfully with VS 2017 & VS 2022, but moment I change it to "LLVM (clang-cl)", I am getting error `"Error   MSB6006 "llvm-lib.exe" exited with code 1".`

After looking at the post "https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/clang-cl-msbuild-integration-fails-for-c-static-li/1218106" I changed `CTLG to "No"`, even then problem  exists.

Please guide.

With Regards.

TausifAhamad.

Comment: This error should be fixed in VS2022. I also tested  `clang-cl`. The static library can be compiled.

Comment: @Minxin, I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current" with "Version 17.1.0". Can you please confirm what version you are using?

Comment: I am using `Version 17.0.5` .

Comment: I created new static library directly in VS2022 and used LLVM clang option. It worked! But I am still facing issues when code is upgraded from VS2017 to VS2022 and enabled LLVM clang.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Consider rebuilding the lib from the start in VS2022.

Comment: Ok. will try it.